# Change onLoad to onClick

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick

So I'm creating a rescission calendar, and need to make some changes to the javascript, not really sure how.

All the code I create has to be inserted into a CMS system, which strips the head/body tag, so I can't use the onLoad function. What I want to have happen, is once they select a date, they click a submit button, and then the rescission date appears.

Here's the code from our previous system which didn't use a CMS:

```
Startscript language="javascript" type="text/javascript"<br>
hoyDate = new Date;<br>
closeDate = new Date;<br>
fundDate = new Date;<br>
resDate = new Date;<br>

monthsi = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');<br>
daysi = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');<br>

function setForm() {<br>
document.form.monthy.options.selectedIndex = closeDate.getMonth();<br>
document.form.datey.options.selectedIndex = closeDate.getDate() - 1;<br>
document.form.yeary.value = closeDate.getFullYear();<br>
}<br><br>

function calcRescission() {<br>
closeDate.setMonth(document.form.monthy.options[document.form.monthy.options.selectedIndex].value * 1);<br>
closeDate.setDate(document.form.datey.options[document.form.datey.options.selectedIndex].value * 1);<br>
closeDate.setFullYear(document.form.yeary.value * 1);<br>
<br>
resDate.setTime(closeDate.getTime());<br>
fundDate.setTime(closeDate.getTime());<br>
<br>
for (i=0; i<=2; i++) {<br>
resDate.setTime(resDate.getTime() + (3600000 * 24));<br>
//check for New Year's Day<br>
    if (resDate.getMonth() == 0 && resDate.getDate() == 1) {<br>
    i--;<br>
    }<br>
//check for Christmas<br>
    if (resDate.getMonth() == 11 && resDate.getDate() == 25) {<br>
    i--;<br>
    }<br>
//check for the 4th of July<br>
    if (resDate.getMonth() == 6 && resDate.getDate() == 4) {<br>
    i--;<br>
    }<br>
//check for Veterans Day<br>
    if (resDate.getMonth() == 10 && resDate.getDate() == 11) {<br>
    i--;<br>
    }<br>
//check for Memorial Day<br>
    if (resDate.getMonth() == 4 && resDate.getDate() >= 25 && resDate.getDate() <= 31 && resDate.getDay() == 1) {<br>
    i--;<br>
    }<br>
//check for Labor Day<br>
    if (resDate.getMonth() == 8 && resDate.getDate() >= 1 && resDate.getDate() <= 7 && resDate.getDay() == 1) {<br>
    i--;<br>
    }<br>
//check for Thanksgiving<br>
    if (resDate.getMonth() == 10 && resDate.getDate() >= 22 && resDate.getDate() <= 28 && resDate.getDay() == 4) {<br>
    i--;<br>
    }<br>
//check for Martin Luther King, Jr observance<br>
    if (resDate.getMonth() == 0 && resDate.getDay() == 1 && resDate.getDate() >= 15 && resDate.getDate() <= 21) {<br>
    i--;<br>
    }<br>
//check for Washington/Lincoln observance<br>
    if (resDate.getMonth() == 1 && resDate.getDay() == 1 && resDate.getDate() >= 15 && resDate.getDate() <= 21) {<br>
    i--;<br>
    }<br>
//check for Columbus Day<br>
    if (resDate.getMonth() == 9 && resDate.getDay() == 1 && resDate.getDate() >= 8 && resDate.getDate() <= 14) {<br>
    i--;<br>
    }<br>
//check for Sundays<br>
    if (resDate.getDay() == 0) {<br>
    i--;<br>
    }<br>

}<br>
j = 0;<br>
fundit = "no";<br>
while (j<=3 || fundit != "yes") {<br>
fundit = "yes";<br>
j++;<br>
fundDate.setTime(fundDate.getTime() + (3600000 * 24));<br>
//checking for Christmas<br>
    if ((fundDate.getMonth() == 11 && fundDate.getDate() == 25) || (fundDate.getMonth() == 11 && fundDate.getDate() == 26 && fundDate.getDay() == 1)) {<br>
    j--;<br>
    if (fundDate.getMonth() == 11 && fundDate.getDate() == 25 && fundDate.getDay() == 0) {<br>
    j++;<br>
    }<br>
    fundit = "no";<br>
    }<br>
//checking for New Year's<br>
    if ((fundDate.getMonth() == 0 && fundDate.getDate() == 1) || (fundDate.getMonth() == 0 && fundDate.getDate() == 2 && fundDate.getDay() == 1)) {<br>
    j--;<br>
    if (fundDate.getDate() == 1 && fundDate.getMonth() == 0 && fundDate.getDay() == 0) {
    j++;<br>
    }<br>
    fundit = "no";<br>
    }<br>
//checking for the 4th of July<br>
    if ((fundDate.getMonth() == 6 && fundDate.getDate() == 4) || (fundDate.getMonth() == 6 && fundDate.getDate() == 5 && fundDate.getDay() == 1)) {<br>
    j--;<br>
    if (fundDate.getDate() == 4 && fundDate.getMonth() == 6 && fundDate.getDay() == 0) {
    j++;<br>
    }<br>
    fundit = "no";<br>
    }<br>
//check for Memorial Day<br>
    if (fundDate.getMonth() == 4 && fundDate.getDay() == 1 && fundDate.getDate() >= 25 && fundDate.getDate() <= 31) {<br>
    j--;<br>
    fundit = "no";<br>
    }<br>
//check for Labor day<br>
    if (fundDate.getMonth() == 8 && fundDate.getDay() == 1 && fundDate.getDate() >= 1 && fundDate.getDate() <= 7) {<br>
    j--;<br>
    fundit = "no";<br>
    }<br>
//check for Thanksgiving<br>
    if (fundDate.getMonth() == 10 && fundDate.getDay() == 4 && fundDate.getDate() >= 22 && fundDate.getDate() <= 28) {<br>
    j--;<br>
    fundit = "no";<br>
    }<br>
//check for Veterans Day<br>
    if ((fundDate.getMonth() == 10 && fundDate.getDate() == 11) || (fundDate.getMonth() == 10 && fundDate.getDate() == 12 && fundDate.getDay() == 1)) {<br>
    j--;<br>
    if (fundDate.getDate() == 11 && fundDate.getMonth() == 10 && fundDate.getDay() == 0) {<br>
    j++;<br>
    }<br>
    fundit = "no";<br>
    }<br>
//checking for Martin Luther King, Jr observance<br>
    if (fundDate.getMonth() == 0 && fundDate.getDay() == 1 && fundDate.getDate() >= 15 && fundDate.getDate() <= 21) {<br>
    j--;<br>
    fundit = "no";<br>
    }<br>
//checking for Washington/Lincoln's Day<br>
    if (fundDate.getMonth() == 1 && fundDate.getDay() == 1 && fundDate.getDate() >= 15 && fundDate.getDate() <= 22) {<br>
    j--;<br>
    fundit = "no";<br>
    }<br>
//checking for Columbus Day<br>
    if (fundDate.getMonth() == 9 && fundDate.getDay() == 1 && fundDate.getDate() >= 8 && fundDate.getDate() <= 14) {<br>
    j--;<br>
    fundit = "no";<br>
    }<br>
//checking for weekends<br>
    if (fundDate.getDay() == 6 || fundDate.getDay() == 0)  {<br>
    fundit = "no";<br>
    if (fundDate.getDay() == 0) {<br>
    j--;<br>
    }<br>
    }<br>

}<br>
//feed rescission end date to form<br>
// document.form.rescissionday.value = daysi[resDate.getDay()];<br>

document.form.rescissiondatey.value = resDate.getDate();<br>
document.form.rescissionmonthy.value = monthsi[resDate.getMonth()];<br>
document.form.rescissionyeary.value = resDate.getFullYear();<br>
//feed funding date to form<br>
document.form.fundday.value = daysi[fundDate.getDay()];<br>
document.form.funddatey.value = fundDate.getDate();<br>
document.form.fundmonthy.value = monthsi[fundDate.getMonth()];<br>
document.form.fundyeary.value = fundDate.getFullYear();<br>

document.form.nowday.value = daysi[closeDate.getDay()];<br>
}<br>
Endscript<br>
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<body onload="setForm();calcRescission();">
<form name="form" action="rescission.html" method="post">
    <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <select name="monthy" onchange="calcRescission()" class="editable">
                <option value="0">January</option>
                <option value="1">February</option>
                <option value="2">March</option>
            </select>
            <select name="datey" onchange="calcRescission()" class="editable">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>

            </select>
            <input name="yeary" onkeyup="calcRescission()" size="7" class="editable">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="rescissionmonthy" readonly size="10" class="rescind">
                <input name="rescissiondatey" readonly size="3" class="rescind">
                <input name="rescissionyeary" readonly size="7" class="rescind">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: _which strips the head/body tag, so I can't use the onLoad function_ - why not? You can always add more `onload` listeners. `window.addListener("load", function () { /* your code here */ });`

Answer (score 1):

You'll get rid of this:

```
<body onload="setForm();calcRescission();">
```

and add this to the script:

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("load", function() {
   setForm();calcRescission()
 }, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying to this. Been on vacation, so couldn't actually try it out. There's something weird with the CMS, because adding the event listener works on my local copy, but not once it's uploaded to our CMS.